# Image rotation translation offset

Tags: c#, image, rotation, drawing, transformation

I built a system that rotates and scales objects using the most left and vertical center point of the object as the origin. After transforming, you can send the objects html/css3 information to the server and c# will attempt to redraw the scene that you created. C# is rotating the objects/images at the same degree but is rotating them from the vertical and horizontal center points this causes the object/images to change dimensions. I already have those changes calculated however there is an offset occurring with the x,y coordinates of the top left of the object/images

This is the method I've been attempting to work out to deal with the offsets:

```
        int[] rotResult = new int[2];

        int[] tLCoord = new int[2];
        int[] tRCoord = new int[2];
        int[] bLCoord = new int[2];
        int[] bRCoord = new int[2];

        int[] tLCoordTmp = new int[2];
        int[] tRCoordTmp = new int[2];
        int[] bLCoordTmp = new int[2];
        int[] bRCoordTmp = new int[2];

        float sin = (float)Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
        float cos = (float)Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);

        tLCoord[0] = (originalX - Math.Abs(xMin));
        tLCoord[1] = (originalY - Math.Abs(yMin));

        tRCoord[0] = origwidth;
        tRCoord[1] = 0;

        bLCoord[0] = 0;
        bLCoord[1] = (origheight * -1);

        bRCoord[0] = origwidth;
        bRCoord[1] = (origheight * -1);

        tLCoordTmp[0] = Convert.ToInt32((tLCoord[0] * cos) - (tLCoord[1] * sin));
        tLCoordTmp[1] = Convert.ToInt32((tLCoord[1] * cos) + (tLCoord[0] * sin));

        tRCoordTmp[0] = Convert.ToInt32(((tLCoordTmp[0] + tRCoord[0]) * cos) - (tRCoord[1] * sin));
        tRCoordTmp[1] = Convert.ToInt32(((tLCoordTmp[1] + tRCoord[1]) * cos) + (tRCoord[0] * sin));

        bLCoordTmp[0] = Convert.ToInt32(((tLCoordTmp[0] + bLCoord[0]) * cos) - (bLCoord[1] * sin));
        bLCoordTmp[1] = Convert.ToInt32(((tLCoordTmp[1] + bLCoord[1]) * cos) + (bLCoord[0] * sin));

        bRCoordTmp[0] = Convert.ToInt32(((tLCoordTmp[0] + bRCoord[0]) * cos) - (bRCoord[1] * sin));
        bRCoordTmp[1] = Convert.ToInt32(((tLCoordTmp[1] + bRCoord[1]) * cos) + (bRCoord[0] * sin));

        if (angle >= 270)
        {
            rotResult[0] = tLCoordTmp[0];
            rotResult[1] = tRCoordTmp[1];
        }
        else if (angle <= 90)
        {
            rotResult[0] = bLCoordTmp[0];
            rotResult[1] = tLCoordTmp[1];
        }
        else if (angle > 90 && angle <= 180)
        {
            rotResult[0] = bRCoordTmp[0];
            rotResult[1] = bLCoordTmp[1];
        }
        else if (angle > 180 && angle < 270)
        {
            rotResult[0] = tRCoordTmp[0];
            rotResult[1] = bRCoordTmp[1];
        }
        return rotResult;
```

Immediately I know there are a few issues dealing with the way this formula works out in regards to coordinate planes and the way that c# and html/css both render visual elements, I've been running small experiments to offset against those and nothing seems to be getting any closer to a solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to first calculate the image X,Y offsets from the top left corner of the object while rotating the image in c# via TranslateTransform and RotateTransform to prevent clipping, then independently calculate the proper X,Y coordinates for the object using the left most center point of the object after that it was only a matter of making a few conditional statements to deal with the quadrant based calculation differences